# How to parse Setup Audit Trail's Date format

Tags: datetime

When looking at a record of the Setup Audit Trail, the date records have a format I can't seem to parse, due to the timezone not being unique -
The records' dates are like: "`22/06/2015 14:41:24 IST (Irish)`".
So the format: "`dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z`" fails, as IST can be any of:

```
Time Zone Abbreviation  Zone Description          Relative UTC
IST                     Irish Summer Time         UTC+01
IST                     Israeli Standard Time     UTC+02
IST                     Iran Standard Time        UTC+0330
IST                     Indian Standard Time      UTC+0530
```

and the "(Irish)" is not part of the Date format standard.

So, my question is - How can one parse this date-time string in a unique and correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's where you can find a list of all recognized Time Zone codes: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/.

You'll need to take your Setup Audit Trail and put it into the context of the Org that you're working with. Does your Org have any locations in Ireland, Israel or Iran? Chances are you can definitely rule out Iran. Without knowing your org, it's likely that `IST` will represent Indian Standard Time or UTC+0530. You'll need to do your due diligence to find out where your admins are located.

Comment: I was trying to figure out where that Irish timezone crept in to the log and just couldn't. 
My org has nothing to do with Ireland and it is no where mentioned in the SalesForce settings.
What I'm worried about is exactly that. If i had known where this timezone came, I could read that metadata, figure out the relevant timezone, and write a simple parsing method for it.